# Strange Behavoir After Latest Update

Tags: malware

I did the latest Update earlier today. Then hours later I was not using the computer, and it was just sitting there idle with nothing to do. Then I noticed the hard drive light flashing constantly, like the computer was working really hard on something. I woke up the log-in to find the computer almost totally unresponsive like the CPU was tied up doing something very intensive. I tried to shut down the computer but it did not respond. I ended up having to switch off the power supply. 
Does anyone have any idea what was going on that grabbed a hold of my computer,and what it was working on? I thought Linux was immune from viruses?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought looks like a hardware issue or driver.

> High CPU usage caused by System Interrupts usually means that a hardware driver is not working properly or there is an issue with the hardware itself. 
>   
> https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/12795-system-interrupts-causing-high-cpu-usage

for Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5788/how-is-an-interrupt-handled-in-linux

Just a thought could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When something like this happens I install the program `iotop` to see what program is using the hard disk:

```
sudo apt install iotop
```

You need to run it with `sudo` powers:

```
sudo iotop
```

The screen looks thus:

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                      
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init noplymouth~pectre_v2 nospec
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
 6147 idle rick        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % python3 /usr/bi~p [dconf worker]
    4 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/0:0H]
 6149 idle rick        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % python3 /usr/bi~s-on-map [gdbus]
    6 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [mm_percpu_wq]
    7 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    8 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_sched]
    9 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_bh]
   10 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
   11 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/0]
   12 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/0]
   13 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/1]
   14 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/1]
   15 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/1]
   16 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/1]
   17 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/1:0]
   18 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/1:0H]
   19 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/2]
   20 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/2]
   21 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/2]
   22 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/2]
   24 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/2:0H]
   25 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cpuhp/3]
   26 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/3]
   27 rt/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/3]
   28 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/3]
```

The screen refreshes every second. To exit press <kbd>Q</kbd>.

Once you know the name of the offending program you can google it. Note the last time I noticed flashing drive light it turned out to be `fstrim` which is a normal process.